# Prove that f(x) can have any value between A and B

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I need to prove the following statement:
Let f be a bounded and continuous function in the interval (a,b). if $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)=A$ and $\lim_{x\to b-}f(x)=B$ and $A\neq B$ then f can get any value between and A and B in the interval (a,b).

What I did:
Let $ g(x) =
\begin{cases}
f(x),  & \text{$a<x<b$} \\
A, & \text{x=a}  \\
B, & \text{x=b} \\
\end{cases}$
. We can see that $g(x)$ is a continuous function in the the interval [a,b]. Therefore, I can use the Intermediate value theorem to prove that for any value between A and B, there exists $a<c<b$ such that g(c) is equal to that value, but in the interval (a,b) , $g(x)= f(x)$, so f(x) can get any value between A and B in the interval (a,b).

My Questions:

1)Can i define a function that is divided to 3 cases?

2)I didn't use the fact that f(x) is bounded, and that seems weird. what is wrong with my proof?

3) I am sure there must be a better way to prove it because the next statement i need to prove the same just for $A=\infty$ and $B=-\infty$(f(x) isn't bounded) and my trick won't work there, that's why I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: 1) Yes. 

2) You did because a function that is continuous between two finite-valued points is bounded. 

3) $f(x)$ does not need to be bounded in this case because your $A$ and $B$ are $\pm\infty$ which means that effectively you have to prove that $f(x)$ gets all values in the $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes, you can, if $A$ and $B$ are finite. You have just extended $f$ to a continuous function on $[a,b]$

2) You have implicitly used it in assuming that $A$ and $B$ are finite. In fact, $|A|, |B|<+\infty$ if and only if $f$ is bounded (why?)

3) If $A=+\infty, B = -\infty$, then for any real $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$, there is $a'>a, b'<$ such that $f(a') < \alpha < f(b')$. So you apply intermediate value theorem to $[a',b']$

Answer (score 0):

1)Yes. It is a relation $R \to R$. You can use three cases, four, n cases - whatever you want. If it is defined unequivocal, and has only one $y$ for each $x$, it is a function.

2)

3) You can try the following:

For any number $t$ in $(a, b)$ we can find $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $a<f(x_1)<t$ and $t<f(x_2)<b$. This is from the limit definition. Then, by the intermediate value theorem, there is $x_3$ that for it $f(x_3)=t$.

Thus argument can be translated into the case of infinite limits. For any $t$ there is $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $f(x_1)<t$ and $t<f(x_2)$, then intermediate value theorem implies what needed to be proved.

Answer (score 0):

You use bounded when you assume $A$ and $B$ are finite. And I think the proof is just fine as-is.

As for the infinite case: say you want to find an $x$ such that $f(x) = c$. Can you use the definition of "goes to infinity" to show that there is an $x_u$ and $x_l$ where $f(x_l) < c < f(x_u)$? Then it reduces to the bounded case.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof for the first problem is right.

Let's see if we can make sense of the second problem. Let's say that we are trying to show that $f$ takes on the value $C$. Via the property of limits, we know we can find some $x_1$ so that $f(x_1) > C$. Also we know we can find some $x_2$ so that $f(x_2) < C$. Consider the interval $[x_1, x_2]$ (or $[x_2,x_1]$ if you accidentally found these values so that $x_2 < x_1$). Then you can apply IVT to $f$ restricted to this interval to get the desired result.